# is there an R function for consolidating the two columns (min + max) into one "range column"?

Tags: r, range

I realize that my question might have two or three parts to it in total.

| gender | MINsal | MAXsal |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Man | 50000 | 59999 |
| Woman | 20000 | 24999 |

Context: I am working with salary range data. My `df` is salary data. It has a `MINsalary` and `MAXsal` attribute. Now I don't know if my target goal is possible, but would like to combine the two columns into one column that somehow stores the data in a range, formatted (min - max). As well as work with it as numeric data. Because I need to order the salary data somehow for my end-goal.

**My goal is to ultimately group by `gender` and plot a histogram to show the values (salary ranges) by `gender`.** Hope that made sense.

I have tried merging the columns together. But the one thing I'm facing issues in is ordering or arranging the new combined merged column. I think the dash in between gets in the way of computing the data into numeric. I understand R syntax for range data is x:x, or 1:30.

Some functions I think are relevant: cut(), cbind(), paste(), as.numeric(), and summary() to see range distribution.

That said, my expected output would be:

| gender | salary_range |
| --- | --- |
| Man | 100000-124999 |
| Woman | 25000-29999 |
| Woman | 0-999 |
| Man | 20000-24999 |
| Woman | 15000-19999 |

Then that would hopefully allow me to group by `gender` and arrange by salary range (low to high).

my original df:
[image: my original df]

Answer (score 2):

You can use `forcats::fct_reorder()` to make `salary_range` a factor with level order based on `MINsal`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(forcats)

salary_data %>% 
  mutate(
    salary_range = paste0(
      format(MINsal, trim = TRUE),  # format() to prevent scientific notation in result
      "-", 
      MAXsal
    ),
    salary_range = fct_reorder(salary_range, MINsal)
  ) %>%
  arrange(gender, salary_data)
```

```
# A tibble: 5 × 4
  gender MINsal MAXsal salary_range 
  <chr>   <dbl>  <dbl> <fct>        
1 Man     20000  24999 20000-24999  
2 Man    100000 124999 100000-124999
3 Woman       0    999 0-999        
4 Woman   15000  19999 15000-19999  
5 Woman   25000  29999 25000-29999
```

Comment: i figured it out, it was a small mistake on my part @zephyrl. thank you so much for the help